# How Do I download a Chrome OS version older than 75?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I am trying to download an old chromebook recovery image to test some things and https://cros.tech/ only supports down to chrome os 75. The recovery image I need is like a chrome os 70 (Or as old as it can get) for the board name octopus.

Does anyone know a place where I can download older chrome os recovery images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer well close to v70. Go to "https://chrome100.dev/#recovery-images" press ctrl+g and type "octopus" and you can download it as old as 72 for octopus.